# How to call dataframe column using another dataframe to repeat code in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I got 2 data frames, first one called df (contain the main data) and second one is df1 (contain the name of all the column in df). And i have a block of code with a structure like this and it must be repeat many times:

```
A = pd.DataFrame({'A': ((df['B'] / df['C']) * 100)})
```

With A, B, C is string from 3 column in df1. 'B' and 'C' is to call out the data from the 'B' and 'C' column in the main data and A is to store it as a dataframe. Is there a way to loop through all the element in df1, with ith loop run the code with ith row of A,B and C?

Basically, it's like:

```
df: main_data
A1 A2 A3 B1 B2 B3 C1 C2 C3
1  2  6  10 ............20
2  3  7  11.............21
3  4  8  12.............22
4  5  9  13.............23
...

df1: columns_name
A  B  C
A1 B1 C1
A2 B2 C2
A3 B3 C3
```

I was expecting a way to loop the code with different parameters from a dataframe with n row, and on the ith loop, it will run the code with data from ith row from the dataframe contain A, B and C

Comment: Can you post an example of the dataset and the expected output?

Comment: @rr_goyal Here's the data set: [Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MFQoVGh-2lJiMV2A0mdytzNRKxQQglJA/view?usp=share_link)_italic_ **bold** `code` 
it's in Vietnamese.
About the output, i want code to read this following csv file, and then replace A, B, C in the code in te question with each row value of these 3 column in the file. 
[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1e90biPE9RbaqzPeb_WK-tTS6U_tDQuWt/view?usp=share_link) _italic_ **bold** `code`
It will look something like: 
Char_Easy_Row=pd.DataFrame({'Char_Easy':((data_df['so_chu_de']/data_df['so_chu'])*100)})... continue loop

Comment: Welcome. This is most likely possible. However it is not yet clear what exactly you expect as output. Because you assign 'A' as dataframe, this even suggests you might expect multiple dataframes. Could you clarify that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A1': [1, 2, 3], 'A2': [4, 5, 6], 'A3': [8, 8, 9],
                   'B1': [1, 1, 1], 'B2': [2, 2, 2], 'B3': [3, 3, 3],
                   'C1': [3, 3, 3], 'C2': [5, 5, 5], 'C3': [7, 7, 7]})

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A1', 'A2', 'A3'],
                    'B': ['B1', 'B2', 'B3'], 'C': ['C1', 'C2', 'C3']})

print(df)
print(df1)
```

Output:

```
   A1  A2  A3  B1  B2  B3  C1  C2  C3
0   1   4   8   1   2   3   3   5   7
1   2   5   8   1   2   3   3   5   7
2   3   6   9   1   2   3   3   5   7
    A   B   C
0  A1  B1  C1
1  A2  B2  C2
2  A3  B3  C3
```

The df1 column names are used to select columns from df. So-called [fancy indexing](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/02.07-fancy-indexing.html) is used for sampling. Column 'C' data is retrieved via .values to divide line by line.

```
arr = df[df1['B']] / df[df1['C']].values * 100

df[['A1', 'A2', 'A3']] = arr

print(arr)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
          B1    B2         B3
0  33.333333  40.0  42.857143
1  33.333333  40.0  42.857143
2  33.333333  40.0  42.857143
          A1    A2         A3  B1  B2  B3  C1  C2  C3
0  33.333333  40.0  42.857143   1   2   3   3   5   7
1  33.333333  40.0  42.857143   1   2   3   3   5   7
2  33.333333  40.0  42.857143   1   2   3   3   5   7
```